# Extract records from vTiger API

Tags: vtigercrm

We use vTiger query Rest API to extract the ticket data to use it for reporting purposes - currently, we have 500,000+ tickets. Considering that one can extract 100 records per page, it takes hours to pull the entire dataset. What are we missing/what options are we not aware of from vtiger to pull the data on a daily basis?

The single option proposed by the support team was to use a reporting module.

Update: we use vTiger Cloud. The database backup can be shared by the support team once every 6 months.

Comment: It is unclear where the database is located. Is it located on an in-house server, or on some-cloud-based server ?   You can always get a backup of that database, and restore it on a local MySQL database, and do some free reporting...... (sure it will take time because you need to know the structure of that database..)

Comment: If you can only get a dump of your database once every six months, I would strongly consider looking for an alternative service, especially if they don't offer you alternatives to access YOUR data.

Comment: Just use sync method on Rest API and fetch records that modified from certain timestamp!

Comment: @EkaterinaPonkratova, You can use Zapier/Make to use the triggers (create/update) to get/update data in Google Sheets. It will be real-time data in Google Sheets if you use it this way. 

For the existing data, you can fetch the records and store in Google Sheets.